# How can I accomplish the following in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have two tables.

table_a:

```
id | data_x   | data_y
--------------------
1     person     joe
2     person     bob
3     amount     200
4     addres     philville
```

tableB:

```
map_id | table_a_id
-------------------
  7          1
  7          3
  7          4          
  8          4
  8          2
```

The result I want is the map_id if it has an entry in table_a for both data_x = 'person' and data_y = '200'

So with the above table B, the result should be

```
map_id
------
   7
```

How can I write that query in SQL?

Comment: Which RDBMS it is for? you have tagged multiple

Comment: mysql and postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This situation is a perfect fit for an unusual SQL operator: INTERSECT. It is a very declarative, efficient and elegant solution for this problem.

```
SELECT Map.map_id
FROM Table_B AS Map JOIN Table_A AS Person ON (Person.id = Map.table_a_id) AND (Person.data_x = 'person')
INTERSECT
SELECT Map.map_id
FROM Table_B AS Map JOIN Table_A AS Amount ON (Amount.id = Map.table_a_id) AND (Amount.data_y = '200')
```

Formally what you are asking for is exactly the intersection of two disjoint sets: the set of map id's that are persons and the set of map id's that have a value of 200.

Please note the INTERSECT operator does not exists in MySQL, but it does in almost all advanced relational DBMS, including PostgreSQL.

Comment: This query is correct (unlike the currently accepted answer) and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your input, the following should get you started using MySQL:

```
SELECT
  map_id
FROM TableB
JOIN Table_A
  ON TableB.table_a_id = Table_A.id
  AND
  ((Table_A.data_x = 'person')
   OR
   (Table_A.data_y = '200')
  )
GROUP BY map_id
HAVING COUNT(table_a_id) = 2
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39189/1).

### Update

As Erwin Brandstetter made explicit: If the data can't be trusted to be inherently consistent (along the lines of your inquiry), one option is:

```
SELECT map_id FROM (
  SELECT map_id, 'data_x' t
  FROM TableB B JOIN Table_A A ON B.table_a_id = A.id AND A.data_x = 'person'
  UNION
  SELECT map_id, 'data_y'
  FROM TableB B JOIN Table_A A ON B.table_a_id = A.id AND A.data_y = '200'
) T
GROUP BY map_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t) = 2
;
```

This should ensure "at least one each". (Alternatives have been suggested by others.) To get "exactly one each", you could try

```
SELECT map_id FROM (
  SELECT map_id, 'data_x' t, data_y
  FROM TableB B JOIN Table_A A ON B.table_a_id = A.id AND A.data_x = 'person'
  UNION
  SELECT map_id, 'data_y', data_y
  FROM TableB B JOIN Table_A A ON B.table_a_id = A.id AND A.data_y = '200'
) T
GROUP BY map_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t) = 2 AND COUNT(DISTINCT data_y) = 2
;
```

See it in action (with additional test data): [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/964bd5/1).
And it works in PostgreSQL as well: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/964bd/1)

Please comment if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and it expands into what I need to apply it to perfectly, thanks.

Comment: With `(9,1)` and `(9,2)` in `tableB`, this query *incorrectly* reports `9` (2x `data_x = 'person'`, but never `data_y = '200'`). Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db7b6/1

Answer (score 1):

This is less elegant than the [`INTERSECT` solution @Malta posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38287672/939860), but it works with the limited capabilities of MySQL as well:

```
SELECT b1.map_id
FROM   table_a a1
JOIN   tableb  b1 ON a1.id = b1.table_a_id AND a1.data_x = 'person'
JOIN   tableb  b2 ON b2.map_id = b1.map_id AND b2.table_a_id <> b1.table_a_id
JOIN   table_a a2 ON a2.id = b2.table_a_id AND a2.data_y = '200';
```

[SQL Fiddle for MySQL.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db7b6/3)
[SQL Fiddle for Postgres.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b5be5/1)

Answer (score 0):

Join the 2 tables, group by map_id, use conditional counting with either count() or sum(), and filter in having clause (I use mysql syntax below):

```
select map_id,
       sum(
           case
               when a.data_x='person' or a.data_y='200' then 1
               else 0
           end
          ) as matches
from a
inner join b on a.id=b.a_id
group by b.map_id
having matches=2
```

The above query assumes that you cannot have more than one record for any map_id where data_x is person or data_y is 200. If this assumption is incorrect, then you need to use either exists subqueries or 2 derived tables.

Comment: Should this work on postgres? it tells me matches doesn't exist when using postgres

Comment: You tagged your question wih 2 different rdbms products, which follow different syntax rules. You need to adapt the syntax to postgresql. Probably you need to repeat the conditional counting in the having criteria. A minimum effort on your side is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a standard `INNER JOIN`.

But I do beg to differ on your result:

```
 map_id if it has an entry in table_a for both data_x = 'person' and data_y = '200'
```

There is not a record in your data set that has both 'person' and data_y = '200' and therefore no mp_id can be returned

Here is a typical `INNER JOIN` relating to your narrative.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    b.map_id
FROM
    TableA a
    INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON a.id = b.table_a_id
WHERE
    a.data_x = 'person'
    AND a.data_y = '200'
```

If more than one `map_id` exists with `data_x = 'person'` and `data_y = '200'` then you will get multiple results but only 1 row per `map_id`

If you want the map_id(s) for records with `data_x = 'person'` or `data_y = '200'` then switch the and in the where statement to or and you will receive map_id 7 & 8.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    b.map_id
FROM
    TableA a
    INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON a.id = b.table_a_id
WHERE
    a.data_x = 'person'
    OR a.data_y = '200'
```

Note this encompasses (7,1)(8,2) because 1 & 2 both have data_x = 'person' and then (7,3) because 3 has data_y = '200' therefore it would return map_id 7 & 8.

Comment: Maybe my wording was off, see mapping (7,1) (7,3)

Comment: that would be or, but then you would also get (8,2) because 2 has data_x of 'person' as well. Are you wanting only the first match?

Answer (score 0):

```
select map_id from
  table_b b 
    left outer join table_a a1 on (b.table_a_id = a1.id and a1.data_x = 'person')
    left outer join table_a a2 on (b.table_a_id = a2.id and a2.data_y = '200')
group by map_id
having count(a1.id) > 0 and count(a2.id) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets do it simple:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT map_id 
    FROM   table_a a1 
    inner join TableB b1 ON a1.id = b1.table_a_id 
    where a1.data_x = 'person'
) as p
inner join
(
    SELECT map_id 
    FROM   table_a a1 
    inner join TableB b1 ON a1.id = b1.table_a_id 
    where a1.data_y = '200'
) as q
on p.map_id = q.map_id
```

You may replace `SELECT * FROM` with `SELECT p.map_id FROM`.
You may add more sub-set-joins to have more conditions.
[sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db7b6/40)